# How to make a scoreboard for the flappy bird?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game for Flappy Bird, I need to make a score counter, it's there, but it's crooked. It counts a whole bunch of points after the first pipe and does not reset them after death. Below I will attach the code itself and the code of the points.

If you can write the code as it will be correct.

```
import pygame#импортирование модуля pygame
import random#Добавляет возможность спавнить разные трубы
pygame.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600#FPS и размеры окна
FPS = 60

window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))#Создание окна
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font1 = pygame.font.Font(None, 35)#шрифты
font2 = pygame.font.Font(None, 80)

imgBG = pygame.image.load('images/fon.png')#Добавление картинок
imgBIRD = pygame.image.load('images/bird.png')
imgPB = pygame.image.load('images/PB.png')
imgPT = pygame.image.load('images/PT.png')
py, sy, ay = HEIGHT // 2, 0, 0 #Значение по py, sy, ay
player = pygame.Rect(HEIGHT // 3, py, 50, 50) #расположение игрока по центру


state = 'start'#состояние старта
timer = 10 #Задержка


pipes = [] #Список труб
bges = [] #Список заднего фона

bges.append(pygame.Rect(0, 0, 288, 600)) #Отображение заднего фона

lives = 3 #Жизни
scores = 0 #Очки

play = True
while play:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            play = False

    press = pygame.mouse.get_pressed() #Нажатие мыши 
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() #Нажатие пробела
    click = press[0] or keys[pygame.K_SPACE]

    if timer > 0:
        timer -= 1


    
    for i in range(len(bges)-1, -1, -1): #Проверка на удаление и добавление фона 
        fon = bges[i]
        fon.x -= 1

        if fon.right < 0:
            bges.remove(fon)

        if bges[len(bges)-1].right <= WIDTH:
            bges.append(pygame.Rect(bges[len(bges)-1].right, 0, 288, 512))##########


    for i in range(len(pipes)-1, -1, -1): #Добавление и удаление труб 
        pipe = pipes[i]
        pipe.x -= 3

        if pipe.right < 0:
            pipes.remove(pipe)###################

    if state == 'start':#Состояние статического 
        if click and timer == 0 and len(pipes) == 0:
            state = 'play'

        py += (HEIGHT // 2 - py) * 0.1
        player.y = py

    elif state == 'play': #Состояние если игрок нажимает на кнопку то оно переходит в состояние игры
        if click:
            ay = -2
        else:
            ay = 0

        py += sy
        sy = (sy + ay + 1) * 0.98
        player.y = py 

        if len(pipes) == 0 or pipes[len(pipes)-1].x < WIDTH - 200: #отображение труб
            pipes.append(pygame.Rect(WIDTH, 0, 52, 200))
            pipes.append(pygame.Rect(WIDTH, 400, 52, 200))


        if player.top < 0 or player.bottom > HEIGHT:#Проверка столкновение с трубами
            state = 'fall'

        for pipe in pipes:
            if player.colliderect(pipe):
                state = 'fall'                
        for pipe in pipes:
            if player > pipe:
                scores += 1



    elif state == 'fall':####Состояние когда игрок не может ничего делать 
        sy, ay = 0, 0
        state = 'start'
        timer = 60
    else:
        pass

                

    for fon in bges: #Отображение заднего фона
        window.blit(imgBG, fon)##########
    for pipe in pipes:#Рисовка труб
        if pipe.y == 0:
            rect = imgPB.get_rect(bottomleft = pipe.bottomleft)
            window.blit(imgPB, rect)
        else:
            rect = imgPT.get_rect(topleft = pipe.topleft)
            window.blit(imgPT, rect)##########

    window.blit(imgBIRD, player)#Рисовка игрока

    text = font1.render('Очки: ' + str(scores), 1, pygame.Color('White')) #Текст очки 
    window.blit(text, (10, 10))

    text = font1.render('Жизни: ' + str(lives), 1, pygame.Color('White'))#Текст жизни 
    window.blit(text, (110, 10))

    pygame.display.update()#Обновление экрана 
    clock.tick(FPS)

 pygame.quit()
```

***Code scores***

```
for pipe in pipes:
    if player > pipe:
        scores += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `if player > pipe:` with `if pipe.x < player <= (pipe.x + 3):` to fix the game adding a bunch of points (instead of adding 1 to the score for each pipe passed so far, it adds 1 if you're **in** a pipe).
Change the `3` of `pipe + 3` by the speed of your pipes (in case of your program it's 3 so I put 3).

For the score not resetting, I suggest replacing this

```py
elif state == 'fall'
        sy, ay = 0, 0
        state = 'start'
        timer = 60
```

by this

```py
elif state == 'fall'
        sy, ay = 0, 0
        state = 'start'
        timer = 60
        scores = 0
```

assuming this is the part that does stuff upon 'death'.

Not sure it'll work, but it may.

**EDIT:**
For any problems like `TypeError`, replace the `pipe` by `pipe.x` in the previous test (`if pipe < player <= (pipe + 3):`) so it gives `if pipe.x < player <= (pipe.x + 3):`. It should work now...

Comment: I corrected the code as you said, but a new error comes up.                                                                    if pipe < player <= int(pipe + 1):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'pygame.Rect' and 'int'

Comment: Ah, ```pipe``` is a ```Rect``` and not an ```int```... I corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks, everything started to work, only we had to add x to player to get if pipe.x < player.x <= (pipe.x +3):